# Subsetting Numpy array using conditional index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, subset

A structured numpy array has a column called "tumorType"
I want to subset and copy this array into a new array based on a few values
for tumorType

new_array_B = masterArray [ (masterArray['ttype'] == 'breastCancer'] | masterArray['ttype'] == "ovarianCancer') ]  works fine.

There are 22 types of tumors and users select all the tumor types they want to study.

How can I create the subsetting condition based on a list or some other collection of
tumors?  selection list may contain 4 tumors (one instance), selection list may contain 8 tumors next instance, etc. Do I loop based on the tumor types an user has selected? (can this loop be inside the selection [ ]?

in R, i do this:  newArray_Df <- subset(masterSet, masterSet$ttype %in% selectlList)

in the process of migrating to Python. Trying to find the equivalent of %in%  operator.

Searched through several sites. No luck so far. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can use `np.in1d`, but if you're coming from R, I strongly recommending looking at [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) and using their DataFrames rather than trying to make do with numpy structured arrays.